# What's the best way to retrieve BigMap values/keys?

Tags: dapps

How are dApp devs currently pulling in a given BigMap's values or keys? I'm pinging tzkt's API after I retrieve the BigMap’s address from the chain and I'm wondering if there's a better, and/or less centralized way to do this?

```
// example on Jakartanet
const response = await fetch(`https://api.jakartanet.tzkt.io/v1/bigmaps/${someBigMapId}/keys`);
```

Comment: Just for your info: you can spin up your own instanse of tzkt and it won't be centralized ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [../<block_id>/context/big_maps/<big_map_id>?[offset=uint]&[length=uint]](https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-big-maps-big-map-id) to get the list of values in a big map. About keys, those are not stored in the tezos node and you need to index them or have a deterministic way to find them.

Comment: Answered my question perfectly, thank you!